# Python defaultdict(list) de/serialization performance

Tags: python, performance, serialization

I am working on a script which needs to process a rather large (620 000 words) lexicon on startup. The input lexicon is processed word-by-word into a `defaultdict(list)`, with keys being letter bi and trigrams and values being lists of words that contain the key letter n-gram using

```
for word in lexicon_file:
    word = word.lower()
    for letter n-gram in word:
        lexicon[n-gram].append(word)
```

such as

```
> lexicon["ab"]
["abracadabra", "abbey", "abnormal"]
```

The resulting structure contains 25 000 keys, each key contains a list with between 1 and 133 000 strings (average 500, median 20). All strings are in `windows-1250` encoding.

This processing takes a lot of time (negligible considering the expected real runtime of the script, but generally taxing when testing) and since the lexicon itself never changes, I figured it might be faster to serialize the resulting `defaultdict(list)` and then deserialize it on every subsequent startup.

What I found out is that even when using `cPickle`, the deserialization process is about twice as slow as simply processing the lexicon, with average values being close to:

```
> normal lexicon creation
45 seconds
> cPickle deserialization
80 seconds
```

I don't have any experience with serialization, but I was expecting deserialization to be faster than normal processing, at least for the `cPickle` module.

My question is, is this result expectable? Why? Are there any ways to store/load my structure faster?

Comment: Have you specified the pickle protocol format? It defaults to ASCII. Select binary version 2 (or the latest with -1) by passing it as the third argument to `pickle.dump()`.

Comment: @KevinThibedeau Specifying protocol format helped a lot. Unpickling is now comparable to normal process, but still a tad slower

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to figure something like this out is to just write a bunch of tests and use [`timeit`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html) to see which is faster. I ran some tests below, but you should try this with your lexicon dict, as your results may vary.

If you want the times to be more stable (accurate), you can increase the `number` argument to `timeit` - it will just make the test take longer. Also, note that the value returned by `timeit` is the total execution time, not the time per run.

```
testing with 10 keys...
serialize flat: 2.97198390961
serialize eval: 4.60271120071
serialize defaultdict: 20.3057091236
serialize dict: 20.2011070251
serialize defaultdict new pickle: 14.5152060986
serialize dict new pickle: 14.7755970955
serialize json: 13.5039670467
serialize cjson: 4.0456969738
unserialize flat: 1.29577493668
unserialize eval: 25.6548647881
unserialize defaultdict: 10.2215960026
unserialize dict: 10.208122015
unserialize defaultdict new pickle: 5.70747089386
unserialize dict new pickle: 5.69750404358
unserialize json: 5.34811091423
unserialize cjson: 1.50241613388
testing with 100 keys...
serialize flat: 2.91076397896
serialize eval: 4.72978711128
serialize defaultdict: 21.331786871
serialize dict: 21.3218340874
serialize defaultdict new pickle: 15.7140991688
serialize dict new pickle: 15.6440980434
serialize json: 14.3557379246
serialize cjson: 5.00576901436
unserialize flat: 1.6677339077
unserialize eval: 22.9142649174
unserialize defaultdict: 10.7773029804
unserialize dict: 10.7524499893
unserialize defaultdict new pickle: 6.13370203972
unserialize dict new pickle: 6.18057107925
unserialize json: 5.92281794548
unserialize cjson: 1.91151690483
```

Code:

```
import cPickle
import json
try:
    import cjson  # not Python standard library
except ImportError:
    cjson = False
from collections import defaultdict

dd1 = defaultdict(list)
dd2 = defaultdict(list)

for i in xrange(1000000):
    dd1[str(i % 10)].append(str(i))  
    dd2[str(i % 100)].append(str(i))

dt1 = dict(dd1)
dt2 = dict(dd2)

from timeit import timeit

def testdict(dd, dt):
    def serialize_defaultdict():
        with open('defaultdict.pickle', 'w') as f:
            cPickle.dump(dd, f)

    def serialize_p2_defaultdict():
        with open('defaultdict.pickle2', 'w') as f:
            cPickle.dump(dd, f, -1)

    def serialize_dict():
        with open('dict.pickle', 'w') as f:
            cPickle.dump(dt, f)

    def serialize_p2_dict():
        with open('dict.pickle2', 'w') as f:
            cPickle.dump(dt, f, -1)

    def serialize_json():
        with open('dict.json', 'w') as f:
            json.dump(dt, f)

    if cjson:
        def serialize_cjson():
            with open('dict.cjson', 'w') as f:
                f.write(cjson.encode(dt))

    def serialize_flat():
        with open('dict.flat', 'w') as f:
            f.write('\n'.join([' '.join([k] + v) for k, v in dt.iteritems()]))

    def serialize_eval():
        with open('dict.eval', 'w') as f:
            f.write('\n'.join([k + '\t' + repr(v) for k, v in dt.iteritems()]))

    def unserialize_defaultdict():
        with open('defaultdict.pickle') as f:
            assert cPickle.load(f) == dd

    def unserialize_p2_defaultdict():
        with open('defaultdict.pickle2') as f:
            assert cPickle.load(f) == dd

    def unserialize_dict():
        with open('dict.pickle') as f:
            assert cPickle.load(f) == dt

    def unserialize_p2_dict():
        with open('dict.pickle2') as f:
            assert cPickle.load(f) == dt

    def unserialize_json():
        with open('dict.json') as f:
            assert json.load(f) == dt

    if cjson:
        def unserialize_cjson():
            with open('dict.cjson') as f:
                assert cjson.decode(f.read()) == dt

    def unserialize_flat():
        with open('dict.flat') as f:
            dtx = {}
            for line in f:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
                vals = line.split()
                dtx[vals[0]] = vals[1:]
            assert dtx == dt

    def unserialize_eval():
        with open('dict.eval') as f:
            dtx = {}
            for line in f:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
                vals = line.split('\t')
                dtx[vals[0]] = eval(vals[1])
            assert dtx == dt

    print 'serialize flat:', timeit(serialize_flat, number=10)
    print 'serialize eval:', timeit(serialize_eval, number=10)
    print 'serialize defaultdict:', timeit(serialize_defaultdict, number=10)
    print 'serialize dict:', timeit(serialize_dict, number=10)
    print 'serialize defaultdict new pickle:', timeit(serialize_p2_defaultdict, number=10)
    print 'serialize dict new pickle:', timeit(serialize_p2_dict, number=10)
    print 'serialize json:', timeit(serialize_json, number=10)
    if cjson:
        print 'serialize cjson:', timeit(serialize_cjson, number=10)
    print 'unserialize flat:', timeit(unserialize_flat, number=10)
    print 'unserialize eval:', timeit(unserialize_eval, number=10)
    print 'unserialize defaultdict:', timeit(unserialize_defaultdict, number=10)
    print 'unserialize dict:', timeit(unserialize_dict, number=10)
    print 'unserialize defaultdict new pickle:', timeit(unserialize_p2_defaultdict, number=10)
    print 'unserialize dict new pickle:', timeit(unserialize_p2_dict, number=10)
    print 'unserialize json:', timeit(unserialize_json, number=10)
    if cjson:
        print 'unserialize cjson:', timeit(unserialize_cjson, number=10)

print 'testing with 10 keys...'
testdict(dd1, dt1)

print 'testing with 100 keys...'
testdict(dd2, dt2)
```

Comment: Thank you for the wonderful and exhausting comparison of available methods. I have chosen the flat de/serialization method as speed is pretty much the only issue here. I have also tried playing with cjson, but it seems that it defaultly encodes/decodes in unicode, which creates inconsistency in my script.

Comment: Also, in my case, cjson file is taking almost twice as much disk space as the flat method one (242 MB for cjson vs 129 MB for flat) while being more than twice as slow (14.6 second deserialization for json vs 6 seconds for flat)